# How to avoid duplicate symbols between 3rd party frameworks

Tags: ios, frameworks, llvm

I have a bit of a dilemma. I have added 2 frameworks into my project and so it just happens that both use JSONKit. So when I compile my project I get duplicate symbols between these 2 frameworks.

I had to add -ObjC -all_load into my build settings otherwise I would get runtime errors (crashes) due to some categories not being compiled.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're getting source, just edit it so that you include JSONKit yourself and remove it from the framework sources. If you're getting just static libraries, write to the maintainers and tell them to weak-link against JSONKit and make it a requirement for using their framework (this is what they should be doing anyway).

Comment: Yeah this is a big problem. I have seen libraries that are purposely missing other required 3rd party because they know it will clash. If you are using -ObjC -all_load I am assuming you are using actual .a files. Maybe you can request the writers for a version without that library.

Comment: Yeah I feared this was going to be the resolution. I wish it was easier to avoid this set of problems.

Answer (score 2):

When you link static-library, linker will embed all symbols into your final binary. (that's why it is named *static*.) Actually there's no good way to strip off specific symbols, because there's no difference between source symbols and newly embedded symbols. Even you can strip off duplicated symbols, nobody can sure that duplicated symbols are same version. If one library used modified version of `JSONKit` library, it will be broken when you replace it with other version.

The only way is getting `.a` file without the duplicated symbols or get the source and compiling them yourself. If the lib makers are not idiots, they should offer some version of library without embedded symbols. If there's no such thing, I strongly recommend not to use that lib. Because it has no concern of symbol conflict which means made by real newbie which means it's full of problems.